# Delete DynamoDB entries with AWS API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am learning AWS API Gateway to manage the api in the cloud and not through express.js. I created the method **DELETE** under a ***resource*** with the following Integration Request.

**Integration Request**

```
Integration Type: AWS Service
AWS Region: us-east-1
AWS Service: DynamoDB
HTTP method: DELETE
Action: deleteItem
Execution role: XXXXXX
Content Handling: Passthrough
```

the execution role is working because i can read/write to DynamoDB. a **Body Mapping Template** that has a `Content-Type: application/json` as follows:

```
{ 
    "TableName": "comments",
    "Key": {
        "commentId": {
            "S": "$context.requestId"
            },
        "pageId": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.pageId')"
            },
        "userName": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.userName')"
        }
    }
}
```

when i try to run the test with a **Request Body** as follows:

```
{
  "pageId":   "breaking-news-story-01-18-2016",
  "userName": "cacevedo"
}
```

I get the following information:

```
Request: /comments
Status: 200
Latency: 80 ms
Response Body

Response Body:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> <head>  
<title>Page Not Found</title> </head> <body>Page Not Found</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me out with this, because i am not able to delete the item. yet it seems that the integration request is working. Am i missing something or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case anyone runs into the same problem. the HTTP verb needs to be a **post** and not **delete** and also is case sensitive so instead of using `deleteItem`. use `DeleteItem`

Comment: Thanks for updating!